# Python: save binary line masks with assigned line width without using CV2?

Tags: python, image, binary, line, mask

now I have starting cord(79,143) and end cord(200,100), width 500 and height 500 of an image and I wan to use them to save a binary mask like pic[image: line mask].
I can use the skimage to save it,but the line width seems fixed,and I do want to use cv2, so is there any other solution to save the mask with custom line width?

and meanwhile ,I have a cv2 program, but it does not work,

I have a program:

`import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = np.zeros((1080,1080,3),np.uint8)
for i in range(3):
    im=np.squeeze(img[:,:,i])
    print(im)
    imgg=cv2.line(im,(0,0),(511,511),255,5)
    masks=Image.fromarray((imgg).astype(np.uint8))
    masks.save("masks"+str(i)+".png")`

and I want to save 3 same masks,but it gave error:

**Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUaRZ.png) != elemsize*nchannels)**

any idea how to solve it?
Many thanks!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV drawing line [function](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga7078a9fae8c7e7d13d24dac2520ae4a2) does have a `thickness` parameter. You can specify it like this:

```
# Setup an empty image
im = np.zeros((500, 500), dtype=np.uint8)

# Draw with thickness
im = cv2.line(im, (79,143), (200, 100), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=10)
```